# Can I automate Google Cloud SDK gcloud init - interactive command

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-sdk, gcloud-cli

Documentation on Google Cloud SDK https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/ directs one to run `gcloud init` after installing it.

Is there a way to automate this step given that `gcloud init` is an interactive command?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

One does not need to run `gcloud init`. Main goal is to make sure credentials are configured and perhaps the project property is set. If you have service-account credentials, gcloud can be configured and ready to go via the following:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=credential_key.json
gcloud config set project my-project
```

For completeness `gcloud init` essentially runs the following steps:

1. **Select configuration** (one of the following)

   - `gcloud config configurations create my_configuration`
   - `gcloud config configurations activate my_configuration`
2. **Set up credentials** (one of the following)

   - (Interactive) `gcloud auth login`
   - `gcloud config set account my_existing_credentials`
   - `gcloud auth activate-service-account`
3. **Set project**

   - `gcloud config set project my_project`

     - List of accessible projects for set credentials can be seen via
       `gcloud projects list`
4. (Optional) **Set default GCE zone** (Compute API must be enabled)

   - `gcloud config set compute/zone my_default_gce_zone`

     - List of zones can be obtained via `gcloud compute zones list`
5. (Optional) **Set default GCE region** (Compute API must be enabled)

   - `gcloud config set compute/region my_default_gce_region`

     - List of regions can be obtained via `gcloud compute regions list`
6. (Optional) **Create default config file for gsutil**

   - `gsutil config -n -o ~/.boto`

Comment: Is it possible to use project_id from the credential_key file?