# gcloud init always returns Error 409 entity already exists

Tags: windows, gcloud

New to gcloud, Windows 10, cmd `gcloud init` always say Error 409 "entity already exists" for whatever name I entered for my very first project. So I tried the Admin Console using Chrome, after several attempts it created a project.

Can I bypass the command line `gcloud init` using the browser-based Console to continue?

Answer (score 0):

See answer on [Can I automate Google Cloud SDK gcloud init - interactive command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379685/can-i-automate-google-cloud-sdk-gcloud-init-interactive-command) which shows what commands you can use instead of `gcloud init`.

If you already have the project, running `gcloud init` should show you that project in a list and you should be able to select it.

You can also do this via

```
gcloud config set project MY_PROJECT
```

after this just run

```
gcloud auth login
```